# Magento: Cannot make changes in Admin after backup

Tags: php, magento

All looks fine. I have changed to urls etc. But I cannot change anything in Admin, no product changes, categories or on system. After clicking save nothing happens. No error too..

Has anybody an idea what the problem is?

```
2016-03-22T07:46:53+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /.../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CacheController.php on line 104
```

Comment: Magento Backup has a known issue where it changes permissions on files, I'm guessing that it mucked stuff up in `var/cache` or `var/session`

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a cache issue. Try clearing the cache via the command line, clearing your cookies and logging back in. I usually run this to hit all the caching.

```
 rm -rf /path/to/basedir/var/*cache/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be an .htaccess problem. I recognized several 301s which stripped away the form data.

This is what I had in my .htaccess

```
## remove /index.php/ from URL (not for admin area)

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php/admin/.*$
    RewriteRule ^(index.php/)(.*)$  $2 [L,R=301]
```

This lines helped me to get rid of the /index.php/ in the paths. As you see I excluded this from the admin urls. However when I decided to rename my admin path for security reasons, the rewrite started to work for the admin area as well.